# how to have one (4 inch) view scale to other views in Xcode (4.7 in, 5.5 in)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have been trying to look for an answer . . . a solution, for HOURS now and starting to get pissed. The whole Autolayout thing seems so confusing in Xcode, I understand how is beneficial for us, but I came across a problem that I can't fix nor seem to find a solution.

Basically the app is like a dress up game, or a place objects on an image type of game where I have a UIImage View of a car, (for example) and when you touch a button to reveal a wheel, it should reveal it on the X,Y,W,H positions where the wheel must go. I have tried this programmatically by using

wheelImageOne.frame = CGRectMake(98, 110, 50, 50);

However, when I run this on the iPhone 6 or 6 plus, it looks way off! I have tried to pin the image every way possible and still does not work, SO, instead of doing it programmatically I decided to just place the image in Interface Builder where it should go and just pin the height, width, trailing space, etc. so it can be in place, and when the button to reveal the wheel is pressed I just reveal it in the code, BUT, now the wheel looks distorted, it is off the car, it DOES stretch but it does NOT stretch the way it is suppose to stretch. Does any one know a way around this? a solution? I was thinking of just going back to the other Xcode and let apple rescale my app for the newer devices but we can't upload apps with older versions of Xcode. Is there a way to do such thing as developing the app for 4 inch and let it rescale by itself? If i do it for 4 inch and upload it, will Apple just simply rescale it to fit the newer devices? I think i like it how it was before. Someone help :-(

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Looks like what you are trying to accomplish will work wit `use size class`. Tick it in the main storyboard under here:[image: Use size class] Then You have to add constraints to the picture of the wheel like so. You select the image in Storyboard, then use the pin tool as seen here:[image][image: Pin tool] Then, ctrl-drag to the side and selct width, and then control drag to the top of the wheel picture and select height. Then on the detail view on the right hand side, and click the red arrow. Press fix constraints and that should make the deal. Hope that helped! Julian

Comment: However, I came across a workaround. So the image of the vehicle is pretty big. Therefore the car rescaled perfectly fine when adding the constraints. It is the parts of the vehicle like the wheels, door handles, etc that are UIImage Views that are just placed above the image of the car. Those images do not rescale the way they're suppose to even though I pin their height and width, etc. The way I managed to work around it was by making the wheel image the same height and width as the car. Then I placed the wheel on top of the other image to overlap and pinned it the same as the car.

Comment: Therefore, the wheel image is a png image that has no color except for the wheel and where it belongs. This works, BUT, it's not a really efficient way, I have to re export each image with new dimensions. I'm pretty sure there must be a way where the small image itself would have the same x,y,w,h properties not mattering the iPhone screen size.

Comment: Yep this didn't work. I know this isn't the solution because I have an old app that stretches to 5.5 4.7 screens, but didn't have these checked too.